# Is "railroad" metric space complete?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, metric-spaces

Let $(\mathbb{R}^2,d)$ be a metric space where
$$d(x,y) = \begin{cases} \|x-y\| &\mbox{if $x$ and $y$ lie on the same line through the origin}  \\ 
\|x\|+\|y\| &\mbox{otherwise} \end{cases}$$

Is it complete?

I think it is not complete. Consider the sequence given by:

$x_0=(1,1)$

$x_1=(1+\frac{1}{2},1+\frac{1}{2})$

$x_2=(1+\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{3},1+\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{3})$

Comment: Your sequence is not a Cauchy sequence, since it is not bounded.

Comment: Anyway, this metric space is complete.

Comment: Maybe this help?

$\lVert x-y \rVert = \lVert x+(-y) \rVert \leq \lVert x \rVert + \lVert -y \rVert = \lVert x \rVert + \lVert y \rVert$

Comment: it's clear that $d_2 (x,y) \le d(x,y)$, but how to get $C>0$ such that $d(x,y)\le C d_2(x,y)$?

Comment: Eucledian metric and that metric are not strongly equivalent, because if you assume there is a constant $c>0$ such that $d(x,y)\leq cd(x,y)_2$ then, if $x_n\to y\neq 0$ and $\|x_n\|=\|y\|$ then you would get $\|x_n\|+\|y\|\leq c\|x_n-y\|,\,\forall n\in\mathbb N$, but this is not true since when $n\to \infty$, $\|x_n-y\|\to 0$ and $d(x_n,y)=\|x_n\|+\|y\|=2\|y\|\neq 0$

Answer (score 3):

I think the way to go is first to characterize what are the possible Cauchy sequences in that metric space. So if $\{x_n\}$ is Cauchy, then either there is some number $N\in\mathbb N$ such that for all $n\ge N$ all elements $x_n$ are collinear, i.e $x_m=\lambda_m x_N$, or there is no such number $N$. If there is no such $N$, then $\|x_n\|\to 0$, because otherwise you would arrive at a contradiction with the assumption that $\{x_n\}$ is Cauchy. Having characterized the Cauchy sequences, it is easy to see that all of them are convergent (in the "noncollinear" case the limit is always $0$).